# Tunnell's theorem

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, computational-number-theory

Is it possible in some way, to use Tunnells's theorem to determine how long it will take a computer, to determine whether a number n, is a possible area of a rational right triangle?

Comment: Using BSD or unconditionally?

Comment: Assuming BSD, the answer is YES! You have to compute the number of times 2 positive ternary quadratic forms represent a number. I think roughly speaking this takes O(n^{3/2}). There was a project in a SAGE days to compute the q-expansion of the ternary form from Tunnell up to 10^{12} (the only reference I found is http://wiki.l-functions.org/LfunctionsAndModularFormsIII/CentralValues may be there are newer ones)

Comment: I have explained in http://www.ias.ac.in/resonance/December2009/p1183-1205.pdf
how BSD and Tunnell's theorem imply that an integer
$\alpha=jn$, with $j\in\{1,2\}$ and $n$ odd, is 
congruent if and only if
$c_j(n)=0$, where $c_j(n)$ is the coefficient of 
$T^n$ in the formal series $g(T)\theta_j(T)$, with  
$$
g(T)=T\prod_{n=1}^{+\infty}(1-T^{8n})(1-T^{16n})\quad\hbox{and}\quad
\theta_j(T)=1+2\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}T^{2jn^2}. 
$$

Comment: @Pacetti: using Chandan's description we have a $\tilde{O}(n)$ algorithm - compute the product mod $T^{n+1}$ using FFT.